# How to authorize IOT Hub events using SSL certificate?

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-iot-hub

I am working with Azure IOT HUB. Can I authorize a device using SSL certificate to send data to IOT HUB. While sending events to IOT Hub using IOT REST APIs, I can only see Authorization header accepting SAS token. I have already provisioned my device with thumbprint of SSL certificate on IOT Hub but not sure how to send events to IOT Hub using certificate authorization.

Comment: I would like to authorize using mutual SSL instead authenticate. The below link I have already gone through is to authenticate. is there any way I can authorize sending events from device to IOT Hub and authorize them using Mutual SSL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Please take a look at the sections in https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/iot-hub-sas-tokens/ that discuss using X.509 certificates with IoT Hub.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, I want to send a payload from device passing ssl certificate thumbprint via rest api to iot hub. I don't want any middle layer to authorise thumbprint coming from device. Is there any way achieving this via azure it hub rest apI. Also I want to authorise not just authenticate using ssl certificate. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Vindu, does Rajeev's response here (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-sas-tokens/#comments) answer your question?

Comment: No Dominic. I think i need to explore more on x.509 certificate on IOT Hub.

Answer (score 0):

For those seeing this question for the first time, I've created a C#-based code sample that shows you how to associate OpenSSL self-signed and self-generated X509 certs with a device registered in Azure IoT Hub, and then use the certs (primary or secondary) in subsequent runtime operations - specifically sending a telemetry message.

https://github.com/tamhinsf/SimpleAzureIoTCerts/